# WP rest api v2 posts filter by 'search' & 'category_name' not working

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, plugins

I am calling the api as `http://examples.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category_name]=uncategorize&per_page=30&order=asc&search=hello`

I am not able to get particular posts from that specific category.
I got all results from all categories.Any suggestions please.

Comment: Are you using the WP4.7 built in rest? Or the plugin?

Comment: I am using WP REST API v2.0 plugin

Answer (score 3):

Since WordPress 4.7 the filter argument for any post endpoint was removed. By the way, the WP API Repo have a plugin 'Rest Filter' for this job:

https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter

Comment: Apparently even with the rest-filter plugin installed, using both ?search or ?filter[s] causes the apis to return any post (like if post_type is set to 'any'). Any ideas?